# What is the best way to accept either custom erc20 token or ether

Tags: solidity, ether, ethereumjs, bsc

I am working on marketplace smart contract where users can sell erc721 tokens. Everything seems to be working.

I wanted to receive the erc20 token and ether both as payment methods. So what I do is to do some coding and I achieved erc20 token payments using the code below:

```
/**
 * @dev Executes the sale for a published NFT and checks for the asset fingerprint
 * @param _nftAddress - Address of the NFT registry
 * @param _assetId - ID of the published NFT
 * @param _priceInWei - Order price
 * @param _fingerprint - Verification info for the asset
 */
function safeExecuteOrder(
    address _nftAddress,
    uint256 _assetId,
    uint256 _priceInWei,
    bytes32 _fingerprint
)
    public whenNotPaused
{
    // Get the current valid order for the asset or fail
    Order memory order = _getValidOrder(
        _nftAddress,
        _assetId
    );

    /// Check the execution price matches the order price
    require(order.price == _priceInWei, "Marketplace: invalid price");
    require(order.seller != msg.sender, "Marketplace: unauthorized sender");

    // Check the asset fingerprint
    _verifyAssetFingerprint(
        IERC721Verifiable(_nftAddress),
        _assetId,
        _fingerprint
    );

    // market fee to cut
    uint256 saleShareAmount = 0;

    // Send market fees to owner
    if (FeeManager.cutPerMillion > 0) {
        // Calculate sale share
        saleShareAmount = _priceInWei
            .mul(FeeManager.cutPerMillion)
            .div(1e6);

        // Transfer share amount for marketplace Owner
        acceptedToken.safeTransferFrom(
            msg.sender, //buyer
            owner(),
            saleShareAmount
        );
    }

    // Transfer accepted token amount minus market fee to seller
    acceptedToken.safeTransferFrom(
        msg.sender, // buyer
        order.seller, // seller
        order.price.sub(saleShareAmount)
    );

    // Remove pending bid if any
    Bid memory bid = bidByOrderId[_nftAddress][_assetId];

    if (bid.id != 0) {
        _cancelBid(
            bid.id,
            _nftAddress,
            _assetId,
            bid.bidder,
            bid.price
        );
    }

    _executeOrder(
        order.id,
        msg.sender, // buyer
        _nftAddress,
        _assetId,
        _priceInWei
    );
}
```

The above code is working now what for erc20 payment only. I want to achieve is to accept either erc20 token or either etheruem as payment to execute order. I don't want to accept both payments at the same time.
Here is my updated code. it seems that I am doing something wrong.

```
 /**
 * @dev Executes the sale for a published NFT and checks for the asset fingerprint
 * @param _nftAddress - Address of the NFT registry
 * @param _assetId - ID of the published NFT
 * @param _priceInWei - Order price
 * @param _fingerprint - Verification info for the asset
 */
function safeExecuteOrder(
    address _nftAddress,
    uint256 _assetId,
    uint256 _priceInWei,
    bytes32 _fingerprint
)
  public whenNotPaused payable
{
    // Get the current valid order for the asset or fail
    Order memory order = _getValidOrder(
        _nftAddress,
        _assetId
    );

    /// Check the execution price matches the order price
    require(order.price == _priceInWei, "Marketplace: invalid price");
    require(order.seller != msg.sender, "Marketplace: unauthorized sender");
    
    // Check the asset fingerprint
    _verifyAssetFingerprint(
        IERC721Verifiable(_nftAddress),
        _assetId,
        _fingerprint
    );

    // market fee to cut
    uint256 saleShareAmount = 0;

if(msg.value == 0){
     // Send market fees to owner
    if (FeeManager.cutPerMillion > 0) {
        // Calculate sale share
        saleShareAmount = _priceInWei
            .mul(FeeManager.cutPerMillion)
            .div(1e6);

        // Transfer share amount for marketplace Owner
        acceptedToken.safeTransferFrom(
            msg.sender, //buyer
            owner(),
            saleShareAmount
        );
    }

    // Transfer accepted token amount minus market fee to seller
    acceptedToken.safeTransferFrom(
        msg.sender, // buyer
        order.seller, // seller
        order.price.sub(saleShareAmount)
    );
}


    // Remove pending bid if any
    Bid memory bid = bidByOrderId[_nftAddress][_assetId];

    if (bid.id != 0) {
        _cancelBid(
            bid.id,
            _nftAddress,
            _assetId,
            bid.bidder,
            bid.price
        );
    }

    _executeOrder(
        order.id,
        msg.sender, // buyer
        _nftAddress,
        _assetId,
        _priceInWei
    );
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to have the same method accept either ETH or ERC20s. You need to create another method (e.g., `safeExecuteEthOrder`), which is a payable method that's able to take in ETH and do logic based on that.

Comment: I also recommend not to accept Eth directly, but WETH, and provide functionality to switch between WETH and Eth. This way you only need to deal in ERC20 tokens. This is what for example Uniswap does

Comment: @LauriPeltonen can you please direct to me an example of using WETH?

Comment: Here's some part where Uniswap does it. https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L252